# When using Emmet package in atom, expanding the abbreviation does not go as i want it to go

Tags: html, emmet, abbreviation

thanks for reading, i have a quick question about emmet in Atom editor.

when i type this abbreviation (Example):

```
form>.form-group>label[for=name]+input.form-control#name[type=text][name=name]^.form-group>label[for=email]+input.form-control#email[type=text][name=email]
```

It expands to:

```
    <form action="">
        <div class="form-group"><label for="name"></label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name></div>
        <div class="form-group"><label for="email"></label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"></div>
    </form>
```

which is already useful, and better than typing it out all the way. but i would like it to expand to:

```
    <form action="">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name"></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email"></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
        </div>
    </form>
```

i know it's not that big of a deal but it would make it a lot easier.